# canvas.drawCircle does not work - while drawLine works - might be caused by using Sherlock?

Tags: android, drawing, actionbarsherlock, android-canvas

I have a strange issue with the standard method `canvas.drawCircle`.

While I run exactly the same code on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4 and on another S2 with 2.1 it works without problems. The same code on an Acer 500 tablet with 4.0.3 does not paint anything when calling `drawCircle` and `drawPath`.

This is the code:

```
    Paint thickLine = new Paint(scalePaint);
    thickLine.setStrokeWidth(0.07f);
    thickLine.setColor(Color.argb(0xff, 0xff, 0x36, 0x33));
    thickLine.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    canvas.drawLine(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.1f, 0.1f, thickLine);
    canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.15f, thickLine);
```

But the `drawLine` works on all three devices!

Also just to mention - the code worked before - then I changed the standard Fragments to SherlockFragments and modified the code in the app in several places - always testing on S3. So I do not know at what stage it started to not work anymore on the Acer.

I also used the old unchanged drawing class that contains this code (before I made all changes to the app) and copied it into the new version which uses Sherlock now - even this stage of the project code does not work anymore as described.

So I guess it might have something to do with Sherlock - however, I do not have any idea how and why - and if at all....

Anyone had some similar experience where `drawLine` works but `drawCircle` and `drawPath` do not?
- with or without use of Sherlock

Many thanks

Comment: I can tell you that this has nothing to do with ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Thank you very much now I can focus on all the other modifications I made... Also, by the way, super job - I started to use Sherlock only recently - but it's just great. Thank's very much for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost unbelieveble but true, just change the target setting (or remove it alltogether) and it will work - it did in my case :-)

Comment: Can I ask what your target settings were to begin with and what you changed them to to get it to work? I am having a problem with drawPath() in Android 4.0.4 in that it's not drawing (but does in earlier versions)

Comment: Now all I have is this:   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
before I also set target and it did not work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried fiddled with the SDK versions but no luck. However in my case I've discovered that Canvas.scale() is not performing in the same way pre and post Android 4.0.

Comment: César, I can't remember exactly what I was doing when I posted these but I have had problems with Canvas.scale() when drawing text. The question and answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799010/drawing-text-on-a-scaled-canvas

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem - Canvas.drawCircle was not working for me.
Luckely, there is another function - Canvas.drawOval. You can use it to draw circle without changing the build target.

```
RectF tmpRect = new RectF();
tmpRect.top = 0;
tmpRect.bottom = diameter;
tmpRect.left = 0;
tmpRect.right = diameter;

//This call will draw nothing
canvas.drawCircle(tmpRect.centerX(), tmpRect.centerY(), tmpRect.width() / 2, selectionPaint);
//This call will draw a circle
canvas.drawOval(tmpRect, selectionPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this problem with Canvas.drawLine() and Canvas.drawRect(). My lines would be drawn but my rectangles weren't.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    int height = canvas.getHeight();
    int width = canvas.getWidth();

    canvas.drawLine(width/2,0,width/2,height,paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0,height/2,width,height/2,paint);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawRect(touchRect, paint);
}
```

However, it started to work when I put a call to View.invalidate() into my onTouchEvent() method because I wanted to draw a rectangle where I touched the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    invalidate();

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        touchRect.left = (int) (x - 20);
        touchRect.top =(int) (y - 20);
        touchRect.right = (int) (x + 20);
        touchRect.bottom = (int) (y + 20);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I got this from reading https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem after changing min Android version from 2.3 to 3. Lines worked but not drawRect if i changed android version back all worked again.
After a lot try and error i found that switching top and buttom coordinates did the trick.

I changed the order from left-top-right-bottom to left bottom-rirht-top and it worked.